# can an expression in c++ change a variable value

Tags: c++

I have this line of code

```
next_step_camera_x_rotation=step_camera_x_rotation+delta_x;
```

and I was wondering if the value of `step_camera_x_rotation` or `delta_x` was altered

Comment: They *could* be. Depends on the type and how that `operator+` overload is implemented.

Comment: only if the `+` or `=` operators have been overloaded for whatever type those are. The default operators won't change any value except `next_step_camera_x_rotation`.

Comment: @Dave, Forgot about `operator=`. Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression can alter value of a variable:

```
v = (a=3) + 3;
```

But the one that you have in the question will not change values of arguments on right side

```
v = a + b;
```

Neither `a` nor `b` will be changed by this expression.

Answer (score 5):

In general, it *should not*, but that does not mean it won't. It really depends on what the types of the objects are and how `operator+` and `operator=` are implemented. If it is a sane implementation, it should not modify either argument, but there is no rule in the language to guarantee that.

If the types are *fundamental* types, then the answer is that the addition will not change the arguments.

Comment: +1 for cutting straight to the sad, gooey innards of C++.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The values of `step_camera_x_rotation` and `delta_x` can change their values internally if they are `volatile` variables.

Comment: An interesting consideration.

Comment: This is a bit off... `volatile` is used to mark variables that are pinned to a hardware location and might *change* the value due to external causes. *But*, that does not mean that if you mark a variable `volatile` it might change its value, the relationship is rather on the opposite direction: if it can change its value by means other than the program, it has to be marked `volatile`.

Comment: I was just cautioning the OP to be aware of volatile variables which can change their values, even if they are not on the left side of an assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're dealing with pathological cases here, values on the right side of the equation can change if a value on one side is a reference to a value on the other side.

E.g. if you have declared:

```
int step_camera_x_rotation = 1;
int delta_x = 2;
int &next_step_camera_x_rotation = delta_x;  // you'd be crazy to do this
next_step_camera_x_rotation=step_camera_x_rotation+delta_x; // delta_x just changed
```

You could achieve similar effects using the preprocessor.